# $http.get() response 500 angularjs and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set up a EF model in asp.net MVC and im using the $http.get() in angularjs to retrieve the data. When the page is rendered i get a 500 (internal server error)

homeApp.js file

```
var homeApp = angular.module('homeApp', []);
homeApp.controller('propertyController', function ($http) {

var vm = this;

    $http.get("/Home/GetAllProperties")
    .success(function (result) {
        vm.Properties = result;
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })

});
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IPropertyQueryRepository propertyRepo;


    public HomeController()
    {
       this.propertyRepo = new 
        PropertyQueryRepository(new KEstatesEntities1());
    }

    public ActionResult Property()
    {   
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAllProperties()
    {
        var result = propertyRepo.GetAll();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Error Message

Failed to load resource: http://localhost:59338/Home/GetAllProperties 
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

console.log(data)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Ive Looked everywhere but cant find out how t solve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: First you should debug and find the line that throws the exception in your C# code.

Comment: The exception  is thrown just after - return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); and result is holding the correct object data

Comment: put a breakpoint in your method and you will be able to see the detailed error information/exception details.

Comment: I did a console log for the returning data to angular. it mentions - A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

Comment: What is return type of `GetAll()` function in `PropertyQueryRepository` class ?

Comment: It returns a List<T> object which holds all the data from my DB table

Comment: Wrap your 2 lines of server code in a try/catch block.  console log out the Exception.Message.  You can call the server directly from the browser url window "http://yourhost/home/getall'.  Set breakpoint in GetAll function.

Comment: I  getting the same exception as the console.log(data) :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the result in your case is not correctly formed. I tried your code with below sample result set and it worked.

```
 public JsonResult GetAllProperties()
    {
        List<Temp> obj = new List<Temp>();
        obj.Add(new Temp("A",1));
        obj.Add(new Temp("B",2));
        obj.Add(new Temp("C",3));

        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public class Temp
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int empid { get; set; }

        public Temp(string n, int id)
        {
            name = n;
            empid = id;
        }

    }
```

Try changing your result set to some static data and check if you are still getting the same error.